# Magento Bundled Product - "Some of the products below do not have all the required options." Error msg

Tags: magento

We have a set of products that are non-configurable bundles. The items inside the bundle are all required. On clicking 'Add to cart' the bundle gets added, but an error message also shows in the cart page, 'Some of the products below do not have all the required options.' Because of this error no 'Proceed to checkout' page is shown.

The bundles DO in fact have the required items. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as this. Hope my explanation helps you...

There are no user-configurable items in the bundle we're offering, so on the product details page we didn't want the messy Magento table of bundle items to display.

Being a clever clogs, I removed it from the layout by adding the following to the bundle product's Design->"Custom Layout Update" attribute:

```
<remove name="product.info.options.wrapper" />
```

The page layout looked great. However, in doing this I had inadvertently removed the inputs telling Magento how many of each item within the bundle to add to the basket. These are required regardless of whether or not the user can configure them.

I found that deleting my layout update made the bundles work as normal again.

I've now used CSS to hide the DIV instead. Simples.

Comment: I actually thought the same, but when I'm using the standard PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle configuration in my layout.xml nothing changes